# Single worker node stalls job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark submit job (PySpark) that works properly 90% of the time, but for 10% it stalls on a specific host. Basically tasks may take seconds to complete on other hosts, but sometimes it grinds to a halt on a host I can identify via the Spark UI. In such cases I end up killing the process and re-running. I am wondering what my options are to mitigate this issue. 
My infrastructure is a standalone Spark 2.1 cluster on EC2 instances running on Amazon AWS. I have considered speculative execution, but my process writes to s3 and I've been advised that specifying speculative execution for processes that end up persisting to s3 is a bad idea. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: My answer is only a guess without knowing the details of your job.
Your problem is not described specific enough, maybe you can include a screenshot of Spark UI, showing what you exactly mean, how you identify this stalling host. What kind of task is stalling.

Answer (score 1):

Stalling at 90% is not unusual if your data is skewed, i.e. you have some partitions with really large amounts of data which can lead to a lot of GC and OOM.

In this case repartitioning the data, e.g. via the RangePartitioner would be a solution.